# Vestal Versions - Rails 3 Support?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, vestal-versions

I'm real interested in using Vestal Versions with Rails 3. Does anyone know if Rails 3 works with Vestal Versions? I've heard some users are running into issue:

ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError: changes is defined by 
ActiveRecord" It uses a field in the model called changes. Not sure if 
there are plans to fix that or not.

But I'm guessing someone has figured out a work around. Care to share?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

theres a fork that is supposed to solve this problem:
 [laserlemon / vestal_versions](http://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions/issues#issue/34)